# Sending "e-mail as" from an account that is forwarding to another account

Tags: email

I have one address, 123@123.com, that is forwarding to another address, xyz@xyz.com. Without access to the 123@123.com address is there a way to still reply to mail sent to 123 as if it is coming from the 123 address?

Comment: It's unclear how this relates to programming. What's the problem, and what have you tried?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about email.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **Maybe**.

Long answer:

If your ISP allows you to set the From: header to be `123@123.com` then it is possible to do this. Some might reject that.

Additionally, you might be restricted from sending mail from the `@123.com` domain if it has an [SPF record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) that prohibits it. Receiving mail servers may drop that as being bogus mail.

If you want to send mail from a particular address you should have access to that account, regardless of forwarding.